# Deployer Script fails to generate PackageStates.php, while same Shell-Command works. (TYPO3)

Tags: typo3

I have a Deploy-Script for a TYPO3-Project which has this "command":

```
within('{{release_path}}', function () {
    run('{{php}} ./vendor/bin/typo3cms install:generatepackagestates --activate-default' );
});
```

I deploy with `./vendor/bin/dep deploy -vvv --install dev`.

The Output of the Issue Deployment-Part is:

```
> cd /var/www/html/deployer/releases/20180620081909 && php ./vendor/bin/typo3cms install:generatepackagestates --activate-default
< The following extensions have been added to the generated PackageStates.php file: core, extbase, fluid, install, frontend, fluid_styled_content, info, info_pagetsconfig, extensionmanager, lang, setup, rte_ckeditor, rsaauth, saltedpasswords, func, wizard_crpages, wizard_sortpages, about, backend, belog, beuser, context_help, cshmanual, documentation, felogin, filelist, form, impexp, lowlevel, recordlist, reports, scheduler, sv, sys_note, t3editor, tstemplate, viewpage, bra_projectfiles_mrt, bra_system, extension_builder, mask, news, realurl, t3adminer, typoscript_rendering, vhs
```

But in my .../deployer/shared/web/typo3conf/ were no PackageStates.php generated.

AND If I do it manually it works fine:

```
[www-data@xyz ~/html/deployer/releases/20180620081909 ] $ php ./vendor/bin/typo3cms install:generatepackagestates --activate-default
The following extensions have been added to the generated PackageStates.php file: core, extbase, fluid, install, frontend, fluid_styled_content, info, info_pagetsconfig, extensionmanager, lang, setup, rte_ckeditor, rsaauth, saltedpasswords, func, wizard_crpages, wizard_sortpages, about, backend, belog, beuser, context_help, cshmanual, documentation, felogin, filelist, form, impexp, lowlevel, recordlist, reports, scheduler, sv, sys_note, t3editor, tstemplate, viewpage, bra_projectfiles_mrt, bra_system, extension_builder, mask, news, realurl, t3adminer, typoscript_rendering, vhs

[www-data@xyz ~/html/deployer/releases/20180620081909 ] 
$ ls ~/html/deployer/shared/web/typo3conf/
LocalConfiguration.php  PackageStates.php  l10n
```

I want to generate this PackageStates.php with the Deploy-Script, and not by hand.

How can I do this?

**Edit1: the deploy.php without the Login-Informations**

```php
<?php
require_once 'vendor/brandung/deployer/recipes/typo3.php';

/**
 * Shared directories
 */
set('shared_dirs', [
    '{{typo3_webroot}}/fileadmin',
    '{{typo3_webroot}}/typo3temp',
    '{{typo3_webroot}}/uploads',
    '{{typo3_webroot}}/typo3conf/l10n',
]);

// Initial upload for composer install process
set('uploadFiles', ['composer_montea.json' => 'composer.json']);

env('composerServer', ['SECRET']);
env('composerUser', ['SECRET']);
env('composerPassword',['SECRET']);


task('deploy:update_code', function () {
    foreach (get('uploadFiles') as $file=>$targetFile) {
        upload($file,'{{release_path}}/'.$targetFile);
    }
});

task('deploy:update_code_live', function () {
    set('uploadFiles', ['composer_montea_live.json' => 'composer.json']);
    foreach (get('uploadFiles') as $file=>$targetFile) {
        upload($file,'{{release_path}}/'.$targetFile);
    }
})->onlyOn(['live']);

task('deploy:update_code_stage', function () {
    set('uploadFiles', ['composer_montea_stage.json' => 'composer.json']);
    foreach (get('uploadFiles') as $file=>$targetFile) {
        upload($file,'{{release_path}}/'.$targetFile);
    }
})->onlyOn(['stage']);

task('typo3:realurl_config',function() {
    within('{{release_path}}', function () {
        run('ln -nfs ext/bra_projectfiles_mrt/Configuration/Plugin/realurl/realurl_conf.php {{typo3_webroot}}/typo3conf/realurl_conf.php' );
    });
});

task('typo3:packagestates_fix',function() {
    within('{{release_path}}', function () {
        run("ln -nfs ../../../../shared/{{typo3_webroot}}/typo3conf/PackageStates.php {{typo3_webroot}}/typo3conf/PackageStates.php");
    });
});

task('typo3:mask_symlink',function() {
    within('{{release_path}}', function () {
        run('ln -nfs ext/bra_projectfiles_mrt/mask.json {{typo3_webroot}}/typo3conf/mask.json' );
    });
});

task('deploy:install_typo3', function () {
    // Continue if --install option is set
    if (!input()->getOption('install')) {
        return;
    }
    // Create the database
    run('mysql -h{{dbHost}} -u{{dbUser}} -p\'{{dbPassword}}\' -P{{dbPort}} -e "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS {{dbName}};"');
    run('mysql -h{{dbHost}} -u{{dbUser}} -p\'{{dbPassword}}\' -P{{dbPort}} -Nse "show tables" {{dbName}} | while read table; do mysql -h{{dbHost}} -u{{dbUser}} -p\'{{dbPassword}}\' -P{{dbPort}} -e "drop table $table" {{dbName}}; done');
    // Install TYPO3 via cli
    run('cd {{release_path}} && {{bin/php_cli}} ./vendor/bin/typo3cms install:setup  --non-interactive --use-existing-database ' .
        ' --database-host-name="{{dbHost}}"' .
        ' --database-port="{{dbPort}}"' .
        ' --database-user-name="{{dbUser}}"' .
        ' --database-user-password="{{dbPassword}}"' .
        ' --database-name="{{dbName}}"' .
        ' --admin-user-name="{{typo3AdminUser}}"' .
        ' --admin-password="{{typo3AdminPassword}}"' .
        ' --site-name="{{typo3Sitename}}"' .
        ' --site-setup-type="site"');

    within('{{release_path}}', function () {
        run('{{php}} ./vendor/bin/typo3cms install:generatepackagestates --activate-default' );
    });

    // Sets up all extensions that are marked as active in the system.
    within('{{release_path}}', function () {
        run('{{php}} ./vendor/bin/typo3cms extension:setupactive' );
    });

    within('{{release_path}}', function () {
        run("cp {{typo3_webroot}}/typo3conf/LocalConfiguration.php {{sharedPath}}/{{typo3_webroot}}/typo3conf/LocalConfiguration.php");
    });

    set('installDone', true);

    // Install / activate Extensions via cli
    // Deprecated
    /*$cmd = 'ls {{release_path}}/web/typo3conf/ext/;';
    $extensionDir = explode(PHP_EOL, (string)run($cmd)->getOutput());

    foreach ($extensionDir as $extension) {
        if (trim($extension)) {
            $cmd = 'cd {{release_path}} && {{bin/php_cli}} ./vendor/bin/typo3cms extension:activate ' . $extension;
            run($cmd);
        }
    }*/
});

task('frontend:grunt',function() {
    within('{{release_path}}', function () {
        run("cd {{release_path}}/web/typo3conf/ext/bra_projectfiles_mrt/capitan &&  ln -nfs {{deploy_path}}/shared/web/typo3conf/ext/bra_projectfiles_mrt/capitan/node_modules node_modules");
    });

    within('{{release_path}}', function () {
        run("cd {{release_path}}/web/typo3conf/ext/bra_projectfiles_mrt/capitan && {{grunt}} project:finish");
    });
});

task('typo3:modifyIndexCopy',function() {
    within('{{release_path}}', function () {
        run("cd {{release_path}}/web/ && rm -f index.php && cp  ../vendor/typo3/cms/index.php index.php");
    });
})->onlyForStage(['staging','live']);

task('typo3:form_yaml_path_fix',function() {
    within('{{release_path}}', function () {
        run("cd {{release_path}}/web/typo3conf/ext/bra_projectfiles_mrt/Resources/Private/Plugins/form/Yaml &&  ln -nfs {{deploy_path}}/shared/web/typo3conf/ext/bra_projectfiles_mrt/Resources/Private/Plugins/form/Yaml/Configurations Configurations");
    });
});

task('typo3:backend_protection', function () {
    upload('.htaccess','{{release_path}}/vendor/typo3/cms/typo3/.htaccess');
    upload('.htpasswd','{{release_path}}/vendor/typo3/cms/typo3/.htpasswd');
})->onlyOn(['live']);

before('deploy:shared', 'deploy:update_code_live');
before('deploy:shared', 'deploy:update_code_stage');
after('mysql:import','typo3:realurl_config');
after('typo3:realurl_config','typo3:packagestates_fix');
after('typo3:packagestates_fix','typo3:mask_symlink');
#after('typo3:packagestates_fix','typo3:form_yaml_path_fix');
#after('typo3:mask_symlink','frontend:grunt');
after('frontend:grunt','typo3:modifyIndexCopy');
//after('typo3:mask_symlink', 'typo3:backend_protection');
```

Comment: Can you post your deploy.php file?

Comment: the typical questions come to mind: are you sure about the same user, ... the same php, ... the same php-configuration (for testing: create a file with phpinfo() output)

Comment: because it runs remote, i think it's the same php-version, the user is www-data, the same, which i connect manually via ssh

Comment: @ThomasLöffler I edited my Question -> any idea?

Comment: "But in my .../deployer/shared/web/typo3conf/ were no PackageStates.php generated"      

why would you expect it in shared? It should be generated in ~/html/deployer/releases/20180620081909/web/typo3conf/

In general, if you generate this file, you absolutely don't want it to be shared across deploys

Comment: In our setup in the releases/.../typo3conf/ are only symlinks (except for ext) that links to the share folder. I'm new to this, and the workflow inside my ne agency - so I can't give you a reason why, only that we do so... In the deploy-script it will be created in every new deploy process.

Comment: The folder `shared` should have only files which need to be shared across the releases. Extensions, PackageStates and LocalConfiguration should be *not* inside `shared`. In my projects, `shared` has the `fileadmin` and the `AdditionalConfiguration.php` for adjustements for the target server.

Comment: Thank you. So I have another task to optimize the deploy-Script of my agency ;)

Comment: @MonTea would you reconsider your accepted answer here? I think mine has the most value and insights for the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After thorough digging I was able to find the reason for the issue.

If you invoke Deployer from your current directory it will use the autoloading of Composer and include, among others, `vendor/typo3/autoload-include.php`. In this file various internal environment variables like `TYPO3_PATH_ROOT` are exported which TYPO3 uses to set up its paths.

The paths in these environment variables match your current working directory and are completely different from the ones in `{{release_path}}`. Thus `install:generatepackagestates` will generate the `PackageStates.php` in your current working directory.

Now one could try to manually fix these but actually this isn't necessary since `{{release_path}}/vendor/typo3/autoload-include.php` is also included when you run `composer install` in `{{release_path}}`. It's just that this file does nothing since it won't overwrite the existing environment variables.

Thus as a workaround you can add this to your `deploy.php`:

```php
add('env', [
    'TYPO3_PATH_APP' => '',
    'TYPO3_PATH_COMPOSER_ROOT' => '',
    'TYPO3_PATH_ROOT' => '',
    'TYPO3_PATH_WEB' => '',
]);
```

This unsets all environment variables relevant to the `typo3/cms-composer-installers`. They are then [set again with the correct values](https://github.com/TYPO3/CmsComposerInstallers/blob/d9b4e06432a233809487cd2299df1d5bef02e079/res/php/autoload-include.tmpl.php) for the deployed release.

I'd suggest adding a separate task which explicitly runs `install:generatepackagestates` with these customizations before:

```php
task('typo3:packagestates', function (): void {
    cd('{{release_path}}');

    add('env', [
        'TYPO3_PATH_APP' => '',
        'TYPO3_PATH_COMPOSER_ROOT' => '',
        'TYPO3_PATH_ROOT' => '',
        'TYPO3_PATH_WEB' => '',
    ]);
    run('{{bin/php}} {{bin/typo3cms}} install:generatepackagestates');
})->local();
after('deploy:vendors', 'typo3:packagestates');
```

Notice that with TYPO3v11 the [`PackageStates.php` file was removed](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/main/en-us/Changelog/11.4/Important-95647-ComposerInstallationsAndExtensionUsage.html#removal-of-packagestates-php). This means that `install:generatepackagestates` is not necessary anymore (and in fact [semi-removed from the TYPO3 Console](https://github.com/TYPO3-Console/TYPO3-Console/releases/tag/v7.0.0)), thus this workaround can be dropped when upgrading from TYPO3v10.

Answer (score 1):

I found a Solution:

I added the following line before `set('installDone', true);`

```
// Copy LocalConfiguration.php and PackageStates.php to shared folder
within('{{release_path}}', function () {
    run("cp {{typo3_webroot}}/typo3conf/LocalConfiguration.php {{sharedPath}}/{{typo3_webroot}}/typo3conf/LocalConfiguration.php");
    run("cp {{typo3_webroot}}/typo3conf/PackageStates.php {{sharedPath}}/{{typo3_webroot}}/typo3conf/PackageStates.php");
});
```

The 2nd Copy-Command is the part that was missing.

Comment: I think you found a solution for your problem, but it seems generally wrong. You don't set in deployer that PackageStates and LocalConfiguration should be in shared folder. They need to be in the release folder.

Why do you add the complete section of installing TYPO3 in the deployer script? This should be done once and not on every deployment, shouldn't it?

Comment: look at this condition **!input()->getOption('install')** the typo3-installing task only executes if the --install parameter was set with the deploy command

Comment: After a while of programming TYPO3 I know now that your are completly right @ThomasLöffler. My solution was not the right one.